# mongod.lock was not a zero-byte file but mongod started anyway

Tags: mongodb, crash, locking

I am using a single instance of a MongoDB running on my local machine and wanted to write an auto-repair routine since the DB would be bundled with a user application I am currently working on.

The [docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/tutorial/recover-data-following-unexpected-shutdown/#indications) say that there is a `mongod.lock` file which indicates that the DB needs to be repaired:

> If the `mongod.lock` file in the data directory specified by dbPath,
>   `/data/db` by default, is *not* a zero-byte file, then mongod will refuse
>   to start, [...]

My `mogod` process starts like a charm, but my repair routine told me that the DB needs to be repaired. The repair routine is just looking for the filesize of `mongod.lock` which was 5 bytes and `cat mongod.lock` gave the following content:

> 9817

So according to the doc quote above I am wondering even if the `mongod.lock` file is definitely *not* a zero-byte file, how could MongoDB start anyway.

Comment: Did you start mongod instance with data/db directory or some other directory path?? Was there any mongod instance running before this???

Comment: There were several instances of mongod running before the last executed instance using the same data/db directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The document refers to the case of running Mongo without journaling. If you have journaling on, then Mongo will try to repair itself. 
The number you are seeing in .lock file is process id. If the process is not running, then the port would probably be not in use, and Mongo may succeed in restarting the process, if data files are not corrupted.

Comment: Ahh, journaling seems to be enable because I am running on a 64-bit machine. However, there are no journal-files in the journal directory. How could I implement an auto-repair routine if I am not able to check the file size being zero due to journaling? I got an error message that I need to repair the database a few weeks ago, so mongo's self-repair does not seem to work...

Comment: Once a checkpoint has been completed,  Mongo will get rid of the old journal files, in case of wired tiger engine. In both cases, may it be Wiredtiger or mmapv1, you never need to run --repair,  if you have journaling turned on. See documentation for details. https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/tutorial/manage-journaling/#recover-data-after-unexpected-shutdown